# Deterministic - BIP32 Derivation Gap Limit

Tags: private-key-import, deterministic-wallets

I'm creating many derived addresses from a `xprv` (HD private key).

I've been reading about the gap limit problem. The gap limit is 20 addresses ahead.

How do I get my wallet to detect funds, in addresses, that have surpassed the gap limit?

i.e. `m/100` derived address transactions would not get detected, until the gap limit is filled. Are there any tricks to get around this?

If not, I plan to bulk import corresponding `WIF` keys for each address. Do people recommend doing this?

Ideally I would like everything controllable via 1 master key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BIP44 gap limit approach is a weak or even broken concept for recovering BIP32 based wallets.

It makes an assumption about the use case of a BIP44/BIP32 based wallet.

**The default limit of 20 (some even use 5) will quickly lead to lost funds in recovery if the wallet was used in non-super-trivial use cases.**

The missing metadata in a BIP39 mnemonic or in BIP32 xprivs tend to make recovery complex and has a **moderate risk of missing funds**.

The ultra-safe(est) way to recover a BIP32 seed without metadata is to derive all possible keys (impossible) and all possible scripts, then, rescan the blockchain. **But yes, your guess is right,... this is infeasible**.

So how to recover?

If you develop a wallet or rescan tool, use a very large gap limit. Maybe 1'000 or 10'000.

### If you are just a novice user?

- Well, just make sure you keep your old backup in case you detected lost funds.
- Don't purely trust a BIP32/39 recovery, make sure all your funds are there
- If not, consult an expert (watch out for fraud, use a trusted person), or research how to extend the gap limit and how to derive multiple script types
- If you are using Electrum, read here about [the gap limits and ways to extend it](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/faq.html)