# hdseed, hdseed, and bitcoin-qt

Tags: client, bitcoin-cli, mnemonic-seed, seed

in bitcoincore,
what is the use of hdseed please?

can we restore a wallet with it?

and above all an address with bitcoin on it

thank you ! for IT

Answer (score 0):

> in bitcoincore, what is the use of hdseed please?

See [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki)

> can we restore a wallet with it?

See [sethdseed](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/sethdseed.html). But I wouldn't use this on any existing wallet with any kind of transaction history. See [creatwallet](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/createwallet.html) argument 3. I have never done this. Before using this I would make backups and test restoring them.

I would greatly prefer to restore a wallet by using the backup and restore feature in the GUI.

> and above all an address with bitcoin on it

I'd guess so, if that address was derived from that seed using BIP-32 and is  within the [gap-limit](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/87551/13866). However I have never tried this.

Answer (score 0):

HDSeed is the most important key of your Bitcoin wallet for Bitcoin Core.
With this key, you can access your whole pool of public and private keys. Which means that you have full control of the assets of that wallet.

With `sethdseed true [key]` in the console of Bitcoin Core, you can import a certain key pool in the current wallet. So when you download Bitcoin Core on a new PC, you can get your wallet back using this HDSeed. This seed is useful because you can write it on some paper or steel to have it safe besides having only backups on hard drives, USBs or other media.

You can find the HDSeed by using the command `dumpwallet [walletname]` and in that dump file you need to search for HDSeed. The big number before it, is the HDSeed. Make sure you have the right one.